# Determine whether the series ${Z_n}$ of complex numbers converges and if so, find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$Z_n$ is given by
$$
Z_n = \left(1 + \frac{i}{n} \right)^n 
$$
I have taken the modulus value of $Z_n$ and found that evaluating the limit as n goes to infinity as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n^2+1}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}
$ gives the limit as 1 however, that doesn’t show that $Z_n$ is convergent.
How should I show that $Z_n$ is convergent?

Comment: we have that $\lim_{n->\infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$, use that fact to conclude

Answer (score 1):

As the comments pointed out, the result is $e^i$. In the real case, you are able to use the natural logarithm. Either you know that there exist a complex logarithm defined on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}^-$ and you conclude just the same.

Otherwise try to put your sequence in trigonometric form $Z_n =|Z_n| * exp(i\theta_n)$ and show that $|Z_n|$ converges to 1 and find the limit of $\theta_n$.

Comment: I used your hints and decided to use the binomial expansion of Zn and indeed found the limit to be e^i!